# td data need to repeat in next page while print or generate dom pdf

Tags: javascript, css, pdf, printing, laravel-dompdf

I have a table with large data. If the data of the a tr does not end on one page, then the rowspan td data will be shown again on the next page. how I can do this ? i have attached an image for better understanding

[image]